# How can I make Spring JPA don't break when repository save list of data with one record has violation?

Tags: spring, list, spring-data-jpa

```
List<User> users = ...     
userRepository.save(users)
```

Don't break the whole process when there only a few dirty records.

I mean can skip the record.

Answer (score 0):

You should check all the elements before save.

```java
List<User> users = userRepository.save(users.stream().filter(user -> isCorrect(user)).collec(Collectors.toList()))
```

You should build the method `isCorrect` which check the element.

Comment: That's something I try to avoid, because I have tons of field need to programmatic check. That's my pain point.

Comment: Bean validation maybe ok for me. :)